# Compute $P\{t\lt X\lt Y\}$ for $t \ge 0$, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables, possibly with different parameters

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> What is $P(t \lt X \lt Y)$ for $t\gt 0$, when X and Y are independent exponential variables with the parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively?

Since X and Y are independent, I got joint PDF to be $\lambda \cdot\mu\cdot 
e^{-\lambda\cdot x-\mu\cdot y}$.

Now that I'm looking for $P(t \lt X \lt Y)$, using the joint PDF, I set it as:
$$
P(t<X<Y)=\int_0^\infty\int_t^y \lambda \cdot\mu\cdot 
e^{-\lambda\cdot x-\mu\cdot y}dxdy
$$

Is this correct? I'm trying to solve it using the online integral calculator but it's not getting the answer.

---

Edit 1: Here are the changes and result I came up with

Edit 2: Fixed my calculation error and got a confident answer:
$$
P(t<X<Y)=\int_t^\infty\int_t^y \lambda \cdot\mu\cdot 
e^{-\lambda\cdot x-\mu\cdot y}dxdy=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}e^{-t(\lambda+\mu)}
$$

I would really appreciate if someone could check if this is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Well, even without the help of online tools, you should be able to compute $$\int_t^y\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$ and to plug the result in the integral with respect to $x$...

Comment: Observe that $t < X < Y$ implies $t < Y$ and hence, the "domain of integration" (as Americans call it) is the set of $y$ such that $t < y.$ Having such a fix $y,$ the domain of integration of $X$ is simply $t < x < y.$ What I am expressing here is that your double integral is wrong.

Comment: @WillM. Since $t<y$, would the limit of the $dy$ integral be from t to $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in Mathematica

```
Probability[ t < x < y, {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]], y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Mu]]}]
```

You will get
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
  & \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\lambda }{\lambda +\mu } & t<0 \\
 \frac{\lambda  e^{-t (\lambda +\mu )}}{\lambda +\mu } & t \ge 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
 \\
\end{array}
$$